# Can a custom keyboard extension identify a user of my companion application in any way?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

Can a custom keyboard app extension detect a specific user’s identity based on settings/credentials/identification mechanism in the companion app or otherwise? By "identifying a specific user", I mean in the context of my own application/service/brand, not personal/phone data on their device.

Or is it always a static keyboard, always unable to determine the user/phone using it?

Comment: What the hell, why so many downvotes without explanation?!

Comment: Probably because you're asking to uniquely identify a user, which Apple has gone to great lengths to prevent.

Comment: Down votes and up votes are supposed to be based on the quality of the question, not on the morality of what the person asking the question is trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree.  I personally didn't provide any votes in either direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to. In your companion app, put whatever identifier you want in the `NSUserDefaults`, and let the keyboard pick that stuff up in its viewDidLoad of its `UIInputViewController` subclass.

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score -1):

No; this is prohibited by Apple.

Comment: Do you have a source specifically citing this? **Edited my question, thanks**