# Sharing images between iOS8 containing app and Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

What is the best way to send images between the containing app and a custom keyboard?
is there a best practice that apple talk about?
is there a hacky way that apple will hate?
is there a framework already that somebody built in github that helps this?
thanks!

Comment: Why you don't start a bounty, or if you found your solution then plz post it here

Comment: Did you find a better solution than using NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score -2):

You can save images in `NSUserDefaults`, see [Save images in NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648518/save-images-in-nsuserdefaults) . And since you have access to `NSUserDefaults` from the keyboard and the app, it works. See my answer in [Can a custom keyboard extension identify a user of my companion application in any way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943631/can-a-custom-keyboard-extension-identify-a-user-of-my-companion-application-in-a/25460173#25460173) .

Note that in order to enable the sharing of a defaults container you have to follow Apple's docs in the [App Extensions programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6).

It's a very simple and effective solution, but I would only recommend it for a few very small images like icons, etc... Don't make `NSUserDefaults` a repository for your camera photos!

If you want to do more complex data sharing, I would contend that a custom keyboard is probably not the correct structure.